# Attribute Error 'list' object has no attribute 'get' in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm facing a issue while getting the data from the 'POST' method I'm getting an error as `Attribute Error at api/Data/SaveUserResponse/ 'list' object has no attribute 'get' Django` .

The response which I get in the payload

```
[{"AuditorId":10,"Agents":"sa","Supervisor":"sa","TicketId":"58742","QId":150,"Answer":"Yes","TypeSelected":"CMT Mails","Comments":"na","TicketType":"Regularticket","Action":"na","AuditSubFunction":"na","AuditRegion":"na"},{"AuditorId":10,"Agents":"sa","Supervisor":"sa","TicketId":"58742","QId":151,"Answer":"Yes","TypeSelected":"CMT Mails","Comments":"na","TicketType":"Regularticket","Action":"na","AuditSubFunction":"na","AuditRegion":"na"}]
```

Views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        auditorid = request.data.get('AuditorId')
        print('auditorid---', auditorid)
        ticketid = request.data.get('TicketId')
        qid = request.data.get('QId')
        answer = request.data.get('Answer')
        sid = '0'
        TicketType = request.data.get('TicketType')
        TypeSelected = request.data.get('TypeSelected')
        agents = request.data.get('Agents')
        supervisor = request.data.get('Supervisor')
        Comments = request.data.get('Comments')
        action = request.data.get('Action')
        subfunction = request.data.get('AuditSubFunction')
        region = request.data.get('AuditRegion')
        print('Region---', region)
        

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s,@TicketType=%s,@TypeSelected=%s,@agents=%s, @supervisor =%s, @Comments=%s, @action=%s, @subfunction=%s, @region=%s',
         (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid,TicketType, TypeSelected, agents, supervisor, Comments, action, subfunction,region))
        return Response(True)
```

urls.py:

```
 path('Data/SaveUserResponse/', SaveUserResponse, name='SaveUserResponse'),
```

Comment: in place of `request.data.get('variable')` use `request.GET['variable']`, like `request.GET['TicketId']`

Comment: I have tried your approach now I'm getting an error as `MultiValueDictKeyError at Data/SaveUserResponse/
'AuditorId'` @EvilReboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.data` is a list with one element based on your error, you need the first element.

You can use `json.loads` to do it:

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':      
         auditorid = request.data[0].get('AuditorId') # notice the [0]
         print('auditorid---', auditorid)
         ...
```

Comment: I'm facing this error `TypeError atapi/Data/SaveUserResponse/
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list `

Comment: I guess `request.data` is already parsed.. in that case, notice that you have a list with one element.. I updated my answer

Comment: This approach I have used earlier  as well this error I'm getting `Attribute Error 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: can you print `request.data`? notice I added the `[0]` of the list..

Comment: Thanks mate able to fix it

Comment: What if I have more than 1 list How could I able to do for all the list. How could I do it where I have n number of list

Comment: Depends on your logic.. you can iterate through items of `request.data`..

Comment: could u pls provide the approach code I have tried like this but it didn't worked getting an error as  `list indices must be integers or slices, not dict` `for x in request.data:
    auditorid = request.data[x].get('AuditorId') ticketid = request.data[x].get('TicketId')
        qid = request.data[x].get('QId') `